# API isn't fetching data properly of a user while mapping and fetching user-details by each user ID

Tags: node.js, reactjs, api, mapping, axios

I have an array of objects with each element having a user-id of the user who has created the particular element. Now in React I'm mapping the array to show the details. Before mapping I call an API through "axios.get" which takes the user-id and returns the user details.
The problem is that the user details returned from the API are not properly loaded.

The API is totally fine but there is some problem in the React front-end.
Is there a better way to do this?

Where I am mapping the feed:

[image: this is where I am mapping the feed.]

Method to call the API and get user-details. posted_by is a global variable.

[image: this is my method to call the API and get user-details]

Comment: We need to see the code in order to be able to help you...

Comment: Please include the code that contains your implementation of ```axios.get```, it would help a lot. Or else, have you inspect by the dev tool? log the http request and see what happened; whether your data is empty or you have some typo on the endpoint or anything.

Comment: I have added the two images of my code

Comment: What is the console.log(res.data) showing?

Comment: console.log(res.data) is showing the required response of the api

Comment: Hey Akash! Welcome to stackoverflow. You should always post your code (properly as text) instead of posting screenshot/image of the code. It will help others to understand, debug and reproduce errors in your code faster. [read here for more details](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are not using ReactJs implementation properly.

1. Reactjs works on re-rendering whenever any state or props is updated. The `getUserById` is an async call and so, by the time API is finished fetching the data, UI will already be rendered. And because, the redux store or react state is not updated with the new data from API, the UI will not be re-rendered with the new data. So, you need to update you state/store with the data from the API after API call is finished. `Updating the value of global variable(by posted_by = res.data) won't work in here`.
2. The API calls should not be made inside the render function. Otherwise, each time react will re-render the UI, you will be making the same API calls. You should move them to some other lifecycle methods.

Hope it helps. Revert for any doubts/clarifications.

Comment: So, how do I do it. What's the best way to do this?